# using angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker and timepicker in a popup

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I need my users to be able to select a specific datetime in an input field.

I would like to use angular-ui-bootstrap library as it avoids the Jquery dependancy.
The problem is that even if it contains a datepicker and a timepicker, it seems it's not possible to have them in a popup with a nice layout.

I found a component that do exactly what I'd like to do with angular-ui-bootstrap:
http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php

The problem is that it uses Jquery and we need to include a lot of javascript files whih makes the page a bit heavy just for this need...

I investigated in the angular-ui-bootstrap github repo, and found [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/220) which contain a plunker sample that addresses partially my problem,  but with this example there is no possibility of selecting the time.

Does anyone know if it's possible at the moment to use angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker and timepicker to select a datetime?

Comment: have you found the answer?

Answer (score 14):

Maybe this can help. I created a date time picker that wraps the date and time pickers.  You can find it here

https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker

Comment: Thanks so much.  This directive saved me much time

Answer (score 5):

The question is some kind of old but in case anybody is still looking for an answer, here is my implementation for timepicker-popup, purely written in angular.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h1lRMakbmoGP9pwQ0V75)

I is a mixture of angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker-popup and timepicker with switchable seconds ability.

So, have fun with it!

Comment: This is not an answer, the user ask for a combination of Angular bootstrap UI and in the example I can see only a time picker.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to use it with a dialog? I made one with dojo and it looks great:

http://jsfiddle.net/eugenia96/t9bae/

```
var dojoConfig = (function() {
    var base = location.href.split("/");
    base.pop();
    base = base.join("/");

    return {
        async: true,
        isDebug: true,
        parseOnLoad: true,
        packages: [{
                name: "demo",
                location: base + "/"
            }]
    };
})();
```